# What is the purpose of 'export' in React component declaration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, ecmascript-6, components

In React (ES6), why do I *sometimes* see this?...

```
class Hello extends React.Component { ... }
```

and sometimes *this*?

```
export class Hello extends React.Component { ... }
```

What is the significance of the `export` keyword? If using webpack, would this require any changes to the webpack.config.js file?

Any info on this would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:

**main-file.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { External } from './external';

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>

      <h1>Hello World (Main File this time)</h1>
      <External />

    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

**external.js** (same directory)

```
export class External extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>This is my external component</div>
  }
}
```

This doesn't work - can you see why??

Comment: This oriented programming component or a modular way, automatically when you put in the path webpack config file that will read your dependencies and include them. In this way it allows you a cleaner and organized programming (from my point of view)

Comment: You should google "ES6 Module Syntax".

Comment: Sorry, are you saying the 'export' one is cleaner? Can you make a comparison as to what you would have to include in `webpack.config` with it, and without it?

Comment: `export` can be used with anything; not just a react component. just learn about export and you'll understand how it works for any code that uses it.

Comment: @Paulos3000 you only add one file dependencies (webpack.config)`With module.exports = {
   entry:. '/ routes.jsx'` for example, the routes.jsx file contains the main modules. This is an example. there are different ways and this is the one I use to just make a transpile a file with all modules.

Comment: @Paulos3000 When you say "This doesn't work" what is actually going on? Are you getting an error from Webpack or from JavaScript/React in the browser?

Comment: `export` keyword details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). Currently it is not supported natively by any of the web-browsers.

Answer (score 25):

Before explain the `export` keyword let me clear something to you.

---

As you have seen around the internet, in every react application you need to use two important things:

1/ <kbd>Babel</kbd>

2/ <kbd>webpack</kbd> or <kbd>browserify</kbd>

## Explaination

#### What is Babel job?

You might heard of `jsx` and `ES6`.

Well, Babel job is Transpile the `jsx` to js and ES6 to ES5 so the browser can understand these two things.

And `export` keyword is a new feature in ES6 let export your `functions`, `variables` so you can get access to them in other `js` files.

ie:

**hello.js**

```
export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>
  }
}
```

**world.js**

```
import { Hello } from './hello';

class World extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div><Hello /> world</div>; // jsx sytanx.
  }
}
```

#### What is webpack job?

Webpack is a module bundler. It takes in a bunch of assets (ie. `hello.js`, `world.js` and your modules (react, react-dom....)) and turns that into one single file.

i.e:

let say that we have the following config for `webpack`

```
// dont need to set hello.js as an entry because we already import it into world.js
module.exports = {

  entry: [
    './src/world.js'  
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

webpack it turn all of your js files and your modules wich imported and it turn it into onne single file `bundle.js`.

**Edit: Solving the problem**

In `jsx`,

always wrap the returned html into `()`.

```
...
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World (Main File this time)</h1>
      <External />
    </div>
  )
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks that is helpful and very clear, but when I try it seems to break the rendering process. Please see the update to my original post...

Comment: Thanks, but still not working! As soon as remove `import { External } from './external';` and `<External />` from my `main-file.js` then it works again. So there's still a problem either with `external.js` or with the `import` statement above... :/ (external.js is exactly as in my original post... copied and pasted)

Comment: just remove the `{}` and try this `import External from './external'` and aslo import `react` in `external` aswell.

Comment: nope. still nothing. just fyi... my main-file.js and external.js are both in the same directory (in case that makes a difference).

Comment: can you take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Reda-bx/d6c54e7cdc1ba84945fbe3bd0f5c5105) and try it ?

Comment: I copied and pasted yours and still not working... I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for...+1

Answer (score 10):

Exporting a value allows you to import it into another file.

If I export this class from the `hello.js` file:

```
// hello.js
export class Hello extends React.Component { ... }
```

Then I can import it and use it in the `greeting.js` file.

```
// greeting.js
import { Hello } from './hello';

export class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Hello />;
  }
}
```

This isn't specific to React and you can use this syntax to import and export any kinds of values in any kinds of JavaScript applications.

After you use a tool like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) to turn this into code that can run in a browser, then you can use a tool like Webpack to bundle all the modules you have used into a single script file that you can serve for the browser.

This module syntax for importing and exporting also provides a useful shorthand for modules that export a "default" value.

```
// hello.js
export default class Hello extends React.Component { ... }

// greeting.js
import Hello from './hello';
```

Generally you'd want to use this form if your module only exports one value.

Comment: Add example for "default" also.. :)

Comment: yeah, `export default` would be more idiomatic for a Component

Comment: Just for information - Currently `export` it is not supported natively by any of the web-browsers. `export` keyword details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).