# Passing props: One of the props `key` is undefined but the other is readable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

Here are the files in question:

**card-list.styles.css**: `src -> component -> card-list -> card-list.styles.css`

```
.card-list {
    width: 85vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

---

**card-list.component.jsx**: `src -> component -> card-list -> card-list.component.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import './card-list.styles.css';
import {Card} from '../card/card.component';

export const CardList = (props) => (
    <div className="card-list">
        {props.monsters.map(monster => (
            <Card key={monster.id} monster={monster}/>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

---

**card.component.jsx**: `src -> component -> card -> card.component.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

export const Card = props => (
    <div>
        {console.log(props.key)}
        <h1>{props.monster.name}</h1>
    </div>
);
```

---

**App.js**: `src -> App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {CardList} from './component/card-list/card-list.component'
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      monsters: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({monsters : users}));
  }

  render () {
    return  (
      <div className="App">
        <CardList monsters={this.state.monsters}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Super new to React and Javascript, my question: In **card-list.component.jsx**, if my terminology is right, I'm passing `key` and `monster` as `props` to `Card` component. While the `monster` prop is accessible, the `key` prop is undefined. Why is the `key` prop coming in as undefined?

**What is the effort I've put in to understand this**: I've searched for generic questions asking why `props.name` is undefined, and there are multiple answers about `setState` happening asynchronously and `componentWillMount` returns a promise and is asynchronous.

**Why is this not duplicate question if the above answer is right?**: Why is ONE of my props `monster` available for use? but `key` alone is `undefined` so not available for use? Why does the asynchronous activity affect one of the props but not the other?

Comment: You've done all the work in writing a thorough question.  Had you considered creating a runnable snippet?

Comment: @Mike I'm sorry, I followed the format of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210938/what-is-the-purpose-of-export-in-react-component-declaration, never posted a JS question before.

Comment: Key is not accessible inside the child component. The key prop is for React to keep track of items in a list. There is no use case for accessing the key internally. The key is a special prop. Have a read about keys [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: @JMadelaine I wish you'd answered rather than commenting so I could at least upvote the effort.

Comment: Also, this is a great question. So nice one for being so thorough  :)

Comment: I will put my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th `key` prop is not accessible inside the child component as it is a special prop.

The `key` prop's main use case is to allow React to keep track of items in a list, to prevent unnecessary re-renders.

There is no use case for accessing the key internally.

Have a read about keys [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Answer (score 1):

The `key` prop in React is kind of a private variable and only meant for the renderer to verify what items changed and what didn't. Hence, you won't be able to access the `key` prop.

Comment: Gotcha. I renamed the property to `name` and I was able to console log it and it printed. Can't believe it was this simple.

Comment: Hey I'm gonna have to accept `JMadelaine`'s answer since I saw his on the comment section first.